# Как создать новую строку для CSV файла?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Создаю БД в CSV файле и есть проблема в создании новой строки.

Есть колонки: `ID; Name; Last Name; Middle name; Age;`
Соответственно: `1;Yrij;Abcd;Qwert;29;` и т.д.
Эти данные я ввел сам в файле, а необходимо программно, т.е. будет функция по считыванию данных с сайта и заноситься в БД.

```
UserData = pandas.Series(data=[61, 'Василий', 'Флешков', 'Капустович', 512,'муж', 111, 121, 'х' ], index=['ID', 'Name', 'First name', 'Middle name', 'Age', 'Floor', 'Weight', 'Growth', 'Family status'])
data = data.append(UserData) # добавлет в конец БД заполененую строку
```

Но выводит ошибку:

> Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name

Comment: вы вероятно хотите CSV (Comma Separated Values), а не SCV. И соответственно вы хотите работать с DataFrame, а не Series и использовать `.to_csv()`  метод, чтобы на диск записать в csv формате. Попробуйте руками создать желаемый csv-файл (пару строк: заголовок + данные) и прочитать его, используя `pandas.read_csv()`--это позволит вам понять как такие данные в `pandas` могут быть организованы. Попробуйте [10 минутное вводное руководство, которое упоминает как `to_csv()` так и `read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: @MaxU: не исправляйте ошибочную терминологию в вопросе: это может помешать людям, с тем же вопросом что и автор его найти. (В ответе или комментарии нужно безусловно упомянуть корректную терминологию).

Answer (score 3):

Добавить одну строку в DataFrame достаточно просто, используя `df.loc[len(df)] = [...]`:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
  ID  Name First name Middle name Age Floor Weight Growth Family status
0  1  Name       Yrij           V  29     2     80    185       married

In [10]: df.loc[len(df)] = [61, 'Василий', 'Флешков', 'Капустович', 512,'муж', 111, 121, 'х' ]

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   ID     Name First name Middle name  Age Floor Weight Growth Family status
0   1     Name       Yrij           V   29     2     80    185       married
1  61  Василий    Флешков  Капустович  512   муж    111    121             х
```

но гораздо эффективнее накопить массив строк и сразу создать готовый DataFrame или создать новый и добавить его к существующему:

```
In [12]: d = [[11, 'Bond', 'James', 'Jnr', 35, 'M', 85, 190, ''],
    ...:      [12, 'Kong', 'King', '', 12, 'M', 2000, 600, '']
    ...:     ]
    ...:

In [13]: new = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=df.columns)

In [14]: new
Out[14]:
   ID  Name First name Middle name  Age Floor  Weight  Growth Family status
0  11  Bond      James         Jnr   35     M      85     190
1  12  Kong       King               12     M    2000     600

In [15]: df = df.append(new)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   ID     Name First name Middle name  Age Floor Weight Growth Family status
0   1     Name       Yrij           V   29     2     80    185       married
1  61  Василий    Флешков  Капустович  512   муж    111    121             х
0  11     Bond      James         Jnr   35     M     85    190
1  12     Kong       King               12     M   2000    600
```

Ну и собственно добавление DataFrame к **существующему** CSV файлу:

```
df.to_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', mode='a', header=None, index=False)
```

PS я бы не рассматривал CSV файл как БД - максимум как времменное хранилище (например для переноса (экспорт/импорт) в другую БД). Попробуйте MySQL / SQLite или HDF (быстрое файловое хранилище - достаточно удобно для обработки и поиска данных при использовании Pandas)